# Cannot create subscription with timestamp using Stripe API

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, stripe.js

### Background

I have a script that creates subscriptions for customers using the Node.js Stripe API.

### Code

After reading the documentation on [how to create subscriptions](https://stripe.com/docs/api/node#create_subscription) I have arrived at the following code:

```
var stripe = require( "stripe" )( "my_TestKey" );

stripe.subscriptions.create({
    "customer":"myCustomer",
    "billing":"charge_automatically",
    "trial_end":"1509186774",
    "items": [ {"plan":"mySubscription"} ] 
})
.then( console.log )
.catch( console.error );
```

### Problem

However, this subscription fails with the following error:

> "error":{"type":"StripeInvalidRequestError","stack":"Error: Invalid
>   timestamp: must be an integer Unix timestamp in the future.\n    at
>   Constructor._Error ...

### What I tried

So, I assumed that my error was in the `trial_end` field, and so I double checked the timestamp in the following websites:

- https://www.epochconverter.com/
- https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php

Which both convert it successfully to a date. 
I also tried making the request with the date in milliseconds but then it obviously didn't work.

### Question

- What am I missing? Why is stripe considering that field a non-valid one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timestamp `1509186774` is for Saturday, 28 October **2017**. The `trial_end` parameter must for a date in the future — maybe you meant to use 28 October 2018, which is `1540722774`.